# sequelize where conditions works before joining tables

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js

ERROR says :Unknown column 'apartment.townId'` in 'where clause'

var conditions = {}` var where = {}

conditions.include = [ { model: req.db.user, required: false }, { model: req.db.apartment, attributes: ['apartmentName'], required: false }, ] if (req.query.searchValue) { where[Op.or] = [ { '$users.name$': { [Op.like]: %${req.query.searchValue}% } }, { '$users.phone1$': { [Op.like]: %${req.query.searchValue}% } }, { doorNo: { [Op.like]: %${req.query.searchValue}% } }, { propertyNo: { [Op.like]: %${req.query.searchValue}% } }, ] } conditions.where = { ...req.query, ...where } let properties = await req.db.property.findAll(conditions) `

Comment: please format the code block wrapping it into special block symbols

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.